# SQL syntax error when creating trigger

Tags: php, triggers

This error appear when I create the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER addperson after insert on person
for each row 
begin 
if(new.persontype='donor') then
  insert into donor('personid','donor-id')values(new.personid,new.personid);
  else 
  insert into enterpreneur('personid','enter-id') values(new.personid,new.personid);
 end;**
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''donor' ('personid','donor-id')values(new.personid,new.personid)' at line 5

Comment: tablenames should be quoted with ` not '. And fields too, only values quoted with '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not to quote your tablenames and fieldnames with apostroph
Use ` character.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER addperson AFTER INSERT ON person
FOR EACH ROW 
begin 
  IF NEW.persontype = 'donor' THEN
    insert into `donor`(`personid`,`donor-id`)values(new.personid,new.personid);
  ELSE
    insert into `enterpreneur`(`personid`,`enter-id`) values(new.personid,new.personid);
  END IF;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

My SQLFiddle not worked... :(

Here my home mysql:

```
$ mysql
mysql> use test
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE person (a varchar(25));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.47 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE donor (a varchar(25));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE enterpreneur (a varchar(25));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER addperson AFTER INSERT ON person
    -> FOR EACH ROW 
    -> begin 
    ->   IF NEW.a = 'donor' THEN
    ->     insert into `donor`(`a`)values(new.a);
    ->   ELSE
    ->     insert into `enterpreneur`(`a`) values(new.a);
    ->   END IF;
    -> END;//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> INSERT INTO person VALUES ('donor'), ('not a donor');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
mysql> select * from donor;
+-------+
| a     |
+-------+
| donor |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I REMOVE THE apostroph BUT THE ERROR STILL APPEAR THE SAME

Comment: Iam not screaming , sorry but am just  saying what i did

Comment: same error? or different? There are other errors also, try snippet from answer...

Comment: thanks but this also didn't work the same error appears again

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5   
@vp_arth   this is the error

Comment: near '' ? You sure? or just remove long 'unnecessary' text?

Comment: yes this is the whole error i write it here as is it